# How to group multiple occurrences by sign, count and show the date of occurrence from to

Tags: sql-server, database

How to group multiple occurrences by sign, count and show the date of occurrence from to .
Each group of code occurrences interrupted by another code is to be shown separately.
All my attempts fail...
thanks for the help in advance

```
Table 

date         sign    Value
2022-10-01    C    6.00
2022-10-02    C    6.00
2022-10-03    C    6.00
2022-10-04    W    8.00
2022-10-05    W    8.00
2022-10-06    W    8.00
2022-10-07    W    8.00
2022-10-10    C    8.00
2022-10-11    C    8.00
2022-10-12    C    8.00
2022-10-26    B    8.00
2022-10-27    B    8.00
2022-10-28    Y    8.00

IDEAL OUTPUT

C 2022-10-01 - 2022-10-03  3   18
W 2022-10-04 - 2022-10-07  4   32
C 2022-10-10 - 2022-10-12  3   24
B 2022-10-26 - 2022-10-27  2   16
Y 2022-10-28 - 2022-10-28  1   8
```

Answer (score 0):

This just needs a standard gaps-and-islands approach. First step is to partition the rows into groups, then you can aggregate:

```
with gp as (
  select *,
    Row_Number() over(order by date)
    - Row_Number() over(partition by sign order by date) g
  from t
)
select Sign, Min(date) FromDate, Max(date) ToDate, Count(*) Qty, Sum(value) Total
from gp
group by Sign, g;
```

Example [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lq1iNWsA)

Comment: Thank you very much! And I tried to do it with loops etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to add the first and last name to the table above.
Big problem is person like John Malk. The sign is to be counted if it occurred in consecutive dates. If it occurs in a different date string, it must be shown separately.
I don't think there is any way to do it like above. Probably need to use a loop ?

```
Table 

name    surname     date         sign    Value              
John    Malk    2022-10-01    C    6.00             
John    Malk    2022-10-02    C    6.00             
John    Malk    2022-10-03    C    6.00             
John    Malk    2022-11-07    C    6.00             
Katie   Sun     2022-10-04    W    8.00             
Katie   Sun     2022-10-05    W    8.00             
Katie   Sun     2022-10-06    W    8.00             
Katie   Sun     2022-10-07    W    8.00             
Jim Folk        2022-10-10    C    8.00             
Jim Folk        2022-10-11    C    8.00             
Jim Folk        2022-10-12    C    8.00             
Arthur  Mand    2022-10-26    B    8.00             
Arthur  Mand    2022-10-27    B    8.00             
Ann Kiss    2022-10-28    Y    8.00             
                        
Ideal Output                        
                        
John    Malk    C   2022-10-01  2022-10-03  3   18
John    Malk    C   2022-11-07  2022-11-07  1   6
Katie   Sun     W   2022-10-04  2022-10-07  4   32
Jim     Folk    C   2022-10-10  2022-10-12  3   24
Arthur  Mand    B   2022-10-26  2022-10-27  2   16
Ann     Kiss      Y     2022-10-28  2022-10-28  1   8
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).